# How to return html without layout in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is javascript

```
$('#course_name, #subject').on('input', () => {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search_courses_list',
        method: 'get',
        data: {
            course: {name: $('#course_name').val()},
            subject: $('#subject').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#course_search_result').html(data)
        }
    })
}).trigger('input')
```

This is the controller method.

```
def search_courses_list
@courses = Course.joins(:segments).where('lower(name) like :str', str: "%#{params["course"]["name"].downcase}%")
if (params["subject"]!="")
  @courses = @courses.where({segments: {subject_id: params["subject"]}})
end
render :search_result, courses: @courses
end

def search_result
  @courses = courses
end
```

I tried to use ajax to directly get the Erb generated text as Html strings and insert them directly into the container I want. Is that possible that I get only the Erb file I want without surrounded by the layout?

Answer (score 2):

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-layout-option

You can do this on your action

```
render layout: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace `render :search_result, courses: @courses` with `render :search_result, courses: @courses, layout: false`